# BeautifulSoup - remove children but keep their contents

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am creating a web **scraper**, and I have issue fetching the pages whose are most likely generated, like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<div >
<code>
    <p class="nt">&lt;my-component</p> <p class="na">v-bind:prop1=</p><p class="s">"parentValue"</p><p class="nt">&gt;&lt;/my-component&gt;</p>
    <p class="c">&lt;!-- Or more succinctly, --&gt;</p>
    <p class="nt">&lt;my-component</p> <p class="na">:prop1=</p><p class="s">"parentValue"</p><p class="nt">&gt;&lt;/my-component&gt;</p>
</code>
</div>
<div>
<code>
    <p class="nt">&lt;my-component</p> <p class="na">v-on:myEvent=</p><p class="s">"parentHandler"</p><p class="nt">&gt;&lt;/my-component&gt;</p>
    <p class="c">&lt;!-- Or more succinctly, --&gt;</p>
    <p class="nt">&lt;my-component</p> <p class="err">@</p><p class="na">myEvent=</p><p class="s">"parentHandler"</p><p class="nt">&gt;&lt;/my-component&gt;</p>

</code>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Most important is content between `code`  tags. Plan is to extract text between

tags (or , remove those

tags and keep the rest of the DOM as it is.

So I need output like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<div >
<code>
  text text and more text
</code>
</div>
</html>
</body>
```

My tries as following..

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


bs = BeautifulSoup(payload, 'lxml')

with open('/tmp/out.html', 'w+') as f:
    for t in bs.find_all():
        
        for q in t.find_all('code'):
            # print(t.text, t.next_sibling)
            f.write(q.text)
```

but this doesn't give good results.. From what I learned, bs main purpose is to extract elements, so that is reason why I tried recreating the dom in another file.

Thanks!

Comment: But you want a simple `code` tag with all the content of the rest of  `code` tags, or, one by one, extract all the content? And also, all the content is all the text that all `p`'s have, yes?

Comment: @MrNobody33 well, all tags that are not `code` shouldn't be modified, saved as they are.  Children tags in `code` tag should be removed but their text should be kept. 2nd question, well yes, from what I experienced, tags inside code are most likely <p> or <span> tags.

Comment: ```for child in bs.find_all('code'):
    print(child.text, child.next_sibling)``` this seems to work, kind off, but idk how to get its parrents,

Comment: Ok, I just posted an answer @fugitive! Hope it works for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

payload='''
<html>
<body>
<div >
<code>
    <p class="nt">&lt;my-component</p> <p class="na">v-bind:prop1=</p><p class="s">"parentValue"</p><p class="nt">&gt;&lt;/my-component&gt;</p>
    <p class="c">&lt;!-- Or more succinctly, --&gt;</p>
    <p class="nt">&lt;my-component</p> <p class="na">:prop1=</p><p class="s">"parentValue"</p><p class="nt">&gt;&lt;/my-component&gt;</p>
</code>
</div>
<div>
<code>
    <p class="nt">&lt;my-component</p> <p class="na">v-on:myEvent=</p><p class="s">"parentHandler"</p><p class="nt">&gt;&lt;/my-component&gt;</p>
    <p class="c">&lt;!-- Or more succinctly, --&gt;</p>
    <p class="nt">&lt;my-component</p> <p class="err">@</p><p class="na">myEvent=</p><p class="s">"parentHandler"</p><p class="nt">&gt;&lt;/my-component&gt;</p>

</code>
</div>
</body>
</html>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(payload, 'lxml')

for match in soup.find_all('code'):
    new_t=soup.new_tag('code')
    new_t.string=match.text
    match.replace_with(new_t)

with open(r'prove.html', "w") as file:
    file.write(str(soup))
```

Output ***(prove.html)***:

```
<html>
<body>
<div>
<code>
&lt;my-component v-bind:prop1="parentValue"&gt;&lt;/my-component&gt;
&lt;!-- Or more succinctly, --&gt;
&lt;my-component :prop1="parentValue"&gt;&lt;/my-component&gt;
</code>
</div>
<div>
<code>
&lt;my-component v-on:myEvent="parentHandler"&gt;&lt;/my-component&gt;
&lt;!-- Or more succinctly, --&gt;
&lt;my-component @myEvent="parentHandler"&gt;&lt;/my-component&gt;
</code>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```